# hashmap and multiple txt files java

Tags: java, hashmap

need to somehow get these two txt files to serve as my key and values, i got the first one in the list working but need to get all the words mapped from both txt files.. I think whats happening is im not parsing through the files correctly. I am able to System.out.println(..) the contents but im recieving null for values so I am missing something big here. anyways new programmer here this is my first post. hi! =)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {


        //Create map structure  **must have import


        Map engJapDictionary = new HashMap<String,String>();

        //user input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter phrase for translation: ");

        //name the user input
        String name = in.next();
        System.out.println( "You wrote: " + name );


        //Load Eng and Jap
        String fileName = "word.txt";
        String fileName1 = "word2.txt";
        String line = null;
        String line2= null;


        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(fileName1);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String parts[] = line.split("\t");

            while ((line2 = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                String parts2[] = line2.split("\t");

                engJapDictionary.put(parts[0], parts2[0]);


                //for each entry in both txt files iterate through i think here. the .put works only for the first entry in both txt files.. =(


                continue;

                //System.out.println(engJapDictionary +"\n");
                //System.out.println(line);

            }
            }

        }catch (IOException e){}

        //Size of the Dictionary!

        System.out.println("The number of entries is: " + engJapDictionary.size());


        // English to Japanese Dictionary


        //Building dictionary the long way


        engJapDictionary.put("me", "Watashi");
        engJapDictionary.put("you", "anata");
        engJapDictionary.put("hat", "boshi");
        engJapDictionary.put("cat", "neko");
        engJapDictionary.put("dream", "yume");
        engJapDictionary.put("house", "uchi");
        engJapDictionary.put("dog", "inu");


//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("you"));
//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("hat"));
//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("cat"));
//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("dream"));
//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("house"));
//        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get("dog"));



        System.out.println( "Japanese word: " + engJapDictionary.get(name ) );
        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.get(name));
        System.out.println(engJapDictionary.containsKey(name));


        //Print the keys!!

        //System.out.println("\n" + engJapDictionary.keySet());


        //Print the values!!

        //System.out.println(engJapDictionary.values());


    }
}
```

Comment: I bet you'll see the error without any help if you format your code properly. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: didn't think id get flammed so soon. =)  i see your point though, formatting is really important.. control k didnt seem to work for me when bringing my stuff over from intellij. it just got all mucked up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `engJapDictionary.put(parts[0], parts2[0]);` for the first word of the first file with all the words of the second file. Then, you don't put any other words of the first file in the `Map`, since you finished iterating over the second file in the first run of the inner loop, so `line2 = bufferedReader1.readLine()` returns `null`.

You don't need a nested loop, just a single loop that reads a line from both files in each iteration:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && (line2 = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
    String parts[] = line.split("\t");
    String parts2[] = line2.split("\t");
    engJapDictionary.put(parts[0], parts2[0]);
}
```

Comment: you are so fast

Comment: thanks for the quick fix.. i shall reflect on this =)

Answer (score 0):

Eran is right so far; some additional explanation: in the first run of the outer loop the inner loop will replace the first entry subsequently with all words of the second file such that only the last word will remain in the map. The next loop runs won't find anything in the second file any more, as it is read entrirely already, thus you get `null` values for the further entries.

But I strongly recommend you another design! Problem with the two files is that you need to manage the data at two totally different locations. Imagine you add a new word, but by accident you place them at different lines in both files – all words in between the affected two indices will be spoiled... Or what happens, if you don't add the word to one of the files at all???

Prefer one single file with entries such as:

```
<english word>=<japanese word>
```

Then you have all corresponding words joined together and you are safe from errors as above. You iterate over one file, split the lines by `"="`, and fill the map with

```
put(parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());
```

Comment: nice! its only 10k words, i shall figure a way to merge txt files then give it a go.. its been loads of fun so far.. ! thanks friend

Comment: @T.M. Well, you can use your current code (fixed variant, of course) for: Open another (third file) and instead of putting the entries to the map write them to the file: `file.printf("%s=%s\n", parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());`

Comment: for some reason i cant seem to utilize file.printf, I could only resolve something like.  System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", parts[0].trim(), parts2[0].trim());

Comment: @T.M. Sorry for late reply, had my sons visiting over weekend... The `printf` function comes with `java.io.PrintStream` class (which `System.out` inherits from) , thus `file` needs to be an appropriately configured instance of... Alternatively, you can use `String.format` analogously and print the returned string to file.

Comment: //join em together

                engJapDictionary.put(line, line2);
//write the new dictionary.  
                bufferedwriter.write(line + " " + line2 + "\n" );   this ended up working great thanks again